# String hash to json in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
string = "{:from_zip_code=>\"90066\", :to_zip_code=>\"12345\", [{:amount=>\"2.8\", :add_on_type=>\"US-A-RR\", :requires_all_of=>{:requires_one_of=>{:add_on_type_v7=>[\"US-A-COD\"]}}, {:amount=>\"12.2\", :add_on_type=>\"US-A-REG\", :prohibited_with_any_of=>{:add_on_type_v7=>[\"SC-A-HP\"]}}, {:amount=>\"5.15\", :add_on_type=>\"US-A-RD\", :requires_all_of=>{:requires_one_of=>{:add_on_type_v7=>[\"US-A-COD\"]}}, :prohibited_with_any_of=>{:add_on_type_v7=>[\"SC-A-HP\"]}}, {:add_on_type=>\"SC-A-INS\", :prohibited_with_any_of=>{:add_on_type_v7=>[\"US-A-REG\", \"US-A-INS\"]}, :missing_data=>\"InsuredValue\"}, {:add_on_type=>\"US-A-NND\"}]}}"
```

Could you please help me to make this string as json or hash like below

```
{ :from_zip_code => "90066",
  :to_zip_code => "12345",
  [
    {
      :amount => "2.8",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Зелёный, Yes, i have tried it at my level but i could not make it as json or hash.

Comment: I have a bad idea, call eval(string) will make it. But it is not safe.

Comment: yes, eval(string) this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 gem install json
```

You would require the gem in your code like this:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'json'
```

Then you can parse your JSON string like this:

```
JSON.parse(string)
```

Comment: JSON.parse(string), this is not working fine for me.